# Top-align "count" cells in moderation tools summary tables

Tags: feature-request, design, 10k-tools

Maybe it's just me, but the summary tables in the moderation tools would be a lot more readable if the "count" columns were top-aligned. It seems like all that's needed is to add `vertical-align: top;` to the `.summary-table td.cnt` CSS rule?

**Edit:** Here's a screenshot.

[image: Example of summary table in moderation tools]

Sometimes an entry in the table spans two or three lines, so it's hard to figure out which line is the first. There are many ways to make this clearer but top-aligning the count would be simple and effective.

Comment: Which summary table? Can you show a screenshot?

Comment: @bluefeet See my edit.